# Creating Firestore document with text field data

Tags: swift, database, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

So im making a sign up page on xcode with firebase and it currently work well but I would like to get more information from the user such as the first name and the last name . Basically I want my code to automatically create a document named with the email of the user that just sign up in the "Users" collection on firestore and after create the field "FirstName" and "LastName" with the text in those textfield! You can see my code below . Thanks for your help in advance. And I also provide a screenshot ( I did it manually to explain what I want it to do )

```
@IBOutlet weak var FirstName: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var LastName: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var Email: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var Password: UITextField!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

@IBAction func SignUpButton(_ sender: Any) {
    if Email.text?.isEmpty == true {
        print("No text in email field")
        return
    }
    if Password.text?.isEmpty == true {
        print("No text in password field")
        return
    }
    if FirstName.text?.isEmpty == true {
        print("No text in first name field")
        return
    }
    if LastName.text?.isEmpty == true {
        print("No text in Last name field")
        return

    }
    SignUp()
}

@IBAction func LoginButton(_ sender: Any) {
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(identifier: "SignInPage")
    vc.modalPresentationStyle = .overFullScreen
    present(vc, animated: true)
}

func SignUp() {

    Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: Email.text!, password: Password.text!) { (authResult, error) in
        guard let user = authResult?.user, error == nil else {
            print("Error \(error!.localizedDescription)")
        return
        }

        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(identifier: "Manager0")
           vc.modalPresentationStyle = .overFullScreen
        self.present(vc, animated: true)

    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: firebase only provides the `displayName`.

Comment: Hey , I just add a screenshot to explain what I want it to do , are you sure that it can be done

Comment: The user object only has a `displayName`, as a person might not have a last name altogether. The closet you can go to achieving your goal is having only `fullName` as a document field.https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebaseauth/api/reference/Protocols/UserInfo.html#displayname

Comment: Ok thanks I will modify that , and do you know how to create a document with the user email? cause I didnt find any documentation about it

Comment: After you have got the authResult, you can use the uid to create the firestore document.

Comment: Set the document key as the uid you can get from https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/manage-users#get_a_users_profile after creating the user.

Comment: Thanks for your help , it seems that it work but not completely, the "users" collection get create but not the document with the user.uid , I have tried multiple thing so do you have any idea of what would be the line of code

Comment: Can you update your code with that?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot get a user's first and last name as Firebase only honours the full name only via [`displayName`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebaseauth/api/reference/Protocols/UserInfo.html#displayname).

Moreover, with email and password login, you only get the email - as Firebase would have no way to get the user's Name. (Suppose a user has Yahoo Email ID - how would it get the name of the user?)